# Can mongoose model update Object Id field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my code

```
setAssignee(req.payload.email, function(assignee){

    //assignee is now a Object Id that get from setAssignee function

    var value = {
        id : req.params.id,
        title : req.payload.title,
        description : req.payload.description,
        assignee : assignee._id,
        targetDate : req.payload.targetDate,
        updatedDate : new Date(),
    };
        var taskObj = new TaskModel(value);

        var query = { $set : value};

        taskObj.update({ id : req.params.id}, query, function(err){
            if(err) { return reply(err); };
            return reply({
                id : req.params.id,
                title : req.payload.title,
                description : req.payload.description,
                assignee : assignee,
                targetDate : req.payload.targetDate,
                updatedDate : new Date(),
            });
        });
    });
 };
```

setAssignee is a callback function to get objectId from other model. and I want to change it at 'assignee' field in my model.

Here is var query log :

```
{ '$set': 
{ id: '10',
 title: 'task11124',
 description: 'description',
 assignee: 5471aad59c93d7dd010ce3c1,
 targetDate: '2014-11-29T20:15:34.000Z',
 updatedDate: Wed Nov 26 2014 11:23:05 GMT+0700 (ICT) } }
```

It unable to update. I think because of assignee: 5471aad59c93d7dd010ce3c1.
Is it a correct format to update this objectId field ?

Did it about assignee: 5471aad59c93d7dd010ce3c1 not have '' (quote) ?

Or I miss something?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: is the 'id' field of taskModel string or Object?

Answer (score 0):

To convert your string to an object of type ObjectId:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5471aad59c93d7dd010ce3c1');
```